# Accessing/ex entity class via JNDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi

I have such entity class

package org.organization.domain;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GenPersonnel")
public class GenPersonnel implements java.io.Serializable {

    //class members and setters, getteres are ommited. Nothing special

}
```

This class is in another jar that is inserted to main project as maven dependency. How can I get such class object via JNDI if I know only class name as string parameter without fully qualifying name? In such case

```
 String entityClazz = "GenPersonnel"
 InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
 Object clasObject = ic.lookup(entityClazz);
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't lookup EJB 3 Entity from JNDI, you can lookup only EJB Session bean.

Look at this post about [EJB JNDI lookup](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.it/2010/09/introduction-to-ejb-30-injection-and.html).

To manage Entity you have to use `EntityManager`, look at this [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/how-to-ejb30-entity-ejb-089954.html).

Comment: Thanks mate. I needed such straight answer